# [PHP]: Read file from another site's API

Tags: php, url, external, fopen

I'm trying to download the file https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/testuser to a string (this file contains the youtube API details from the user 'testuser'). But when I download it with fopen I just get a blank file. I searched a bit but nothing helped, what could be wrong? I tested the same code with a file from the same server and it worked.

Also, I know it's possible because some sites do exactly what I'm trying to do (such as SocialBlade)

Comment: Use file_get_contents or CURL.

Answer (score 0):

did you try [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) check if you get the file using this..

Answer (score 0):

Try with [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Seems more appropriate.
Beware of the [allow-url-fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen%22) setting

If you are on a hosting service on a shared server, Chances are high that you can not change the allow-url-fopen configuration since it is in [PHP_INI_SYSTEM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) mode. Ask your hosting service for more information about this.